# Zend framework Error handling with ACL

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling, acl

I have implemented database driven ACL functionality using controller `plugin predispatch()` function.

It's working fine. But it stopped requests to be sent on my error controller.

for example if specified controller / Action is not defined then system shows message "Access Denied" instead of showing "Request / Page not found".

So my question how can I implement both ACl and error handling in single plugin using `predispatch()` method.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller plugin, redirect to the error controller if necessary:

```
$request
  ->setModuleName('default')
  ->setControllerName('error')
  ->setActionName('access')
  ->setDispatched(true);
```

The accessAction has to be put into the error controller if you want a special page, or you can simply use the existing errorAction

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. I think You did notgot what I am asking

Comment: Then your question might be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

You should set permission for error controller in your DB.

So current user(role id) should have permission to access the error controller.

I don't know you're structure of DB tables but in my way(probably is similar):

```
INSERT INTO "resources" ("id","name","description") VALUES (11,'error', 'Error controller');
INSERT INTO "permissions" ("role_id", "resource_id", "is_allowed") VALUES (1, 11, 't');
```

First insert in resource table and then in permission table.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your error controller to your ACL plugin by default for all users.

```
if (!$this->has('Default_Error')) {
    $this->addResource('Default_Error');
    $this->allow('guest', 'Default_Error');
}
```

This way everyone is allowed to see error controller.